# Is there a numpy function or some way of improve the next nested for loops?

Tags: python

I am trying to compute a corranking matrix but the time complexity is really high even using numpy ndarrays, the code is the following:

```
def coranking(self, HD: np.ndarray, LD: np.ndarray):
    try:
        if HD.size != LD.size:
            raise CorankingException("matrices hdpd and ldpd do not have the same sizes")

        nbr = HD.shape[0]
        sss = HD.shape[1]

        self.ndx1 = np.transpose(np.argsort(HD, axis=1))
        self.ndx2 = np.transpose(np.argsort(LD, axis=1))

        self.ndx4 = np.zeros((nbr, sss), dtype=np.uint32)

        print(sss)
        print(nbr)

        start = timer()
        for j in range(sss):
            for i in range(nbr):
                self.ndx4[self.ndx2[i, j], j] = i
        print(f"FIRST O(N^2) process =>, {timer() - start:0.4f} sec")

        del self.ndx2

        c = np.zeros((nbr, sss), dtype=np.uint32)

        start = timer()
        for j in range(sss):
            for i in range(nbr):
                h = self.ndx4[self.ndx1[i, j], j]
                c[i, h] += 1
        print(f"SECOND O(N^2) process =>, {timer() - start:0.4f} sec")
        del self.ndx1, self.ndx4

        c = np.delete(c, 0, axis=0)
        c = np.delete(c, 0, axis=1)

        return c
```

Those nested for loops need a lot of time to get executed, in my machine it takes almost 8 seconds for the first one and 80 seconds to the second one, i have tried to use the multiprocessing module but i have not idea how to implement it in this case, how can i have a lower complexity time to this algorithm?

Comment: Have you looked at vector/array indexing? I think this would solve a few of your problems: https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/02.07-fancy-indexing.html

Comment: "but the time complexity is really high even using numpy ndarrays" numpy arrays generally never have better *time complexity*. In fact, for many things it's worse

Comment: Why is there a loose `try` near the top, without an `except`?

Comment: @jhso Thanks i have read some parts of that link and it really speed the algorithm

Answer (score 0):

I figure out how to make it faster, instead of

```
for j in range(sss):
    for i in range(nbr):
        self.ndx4[self.ndx2[i, j], j] = i
```

and this

```
for j in range(sss):
    for i in range(nbr):
        h = self.ndx4[self.ndx1[i, j], j]
        c[i, h] += 1
```

I do the following:

```
range_nbr = range(nbr)  # nbr is the number of points of the data input
for j in range(sss):
    self.ndx4[self.ndx2[range_nbr, j], j] = range_nbr
```

And for the second nested for loop

```
for j in range(sss):
    h = self.ndx4[self.ndx1[range_nbr, j], j]
    c[range_nbr, h] += nbr
```

in the past the algorithm took almost 80 sec to be executed, with this it decrease to 13 secs, and i think it can be faster implementing multiprocessing